# Idiomatic way to get one of possible values in a map?

Tags: clojure

What is the best way to get the first non nil value of several possible keys in a map.

Example:

```
(get-first-matching {:fum 4 :bar 41 :baz 45} [:foo :bar :baz])
;=> 41
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[some](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some).

```
user=> (some {:fum 4 :bar 41 :baz 45} [:foo :bar :baz])
41
```

Comment: It is interesting to note that the map is being used here as  predicate function that is called with the collection of keys. Therefore what you will get is not strictly the first non-nil value but the first "truthy" value. Try `(some {:foo nil :bar false :baz 20} [:foo :bar :baz])` for example.

Comment: Right, so a version that works for values that are nil or false looks like `(when-let [[k v] (some #(find m %) [:foo :bar :baz])] v)`.